# Determining value for 'k' for minute and hour hand given a condition in swapping problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, puzzle

In problems where minute and hour hand interchange their places, I read a couple of posts here.

The following post gives a general formula to get the values of all such possible cases in a day:

[After swapping the positions of the hour and the minute hand, when will a clock still give a valid time?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59379/after-swapping-the-positions-of-the-hour-and-the-minute-hand-when-will-a-clock)

And the following 2 involved application of the same concept but were resolved using different approaches:

1. [Clock hands moving to take each others places.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4082551/clock-hands-moving-to-take-each-others-places?rq=1)
2. [Minute hand and hour hand interchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237818/minute-hand-and-hour-hand-interchange)

When I tried the above 2 questions using the general formula, I could not, without the help of excel. I need to be able to do it using pen and paper only and that too in say 2-3 mins.

Here's the general formula that was obtained from the post:

In degrees:- Hour Hand = $\frac{360k}{143}$ and Min Hand = $\frac{360k}{143}*12$

With respect to the 2nd question where the hour hand was between 4 and 5 while the minute hand between 5 and 6 on a clock before the swap, I made the following futile attempt:

$120<\frac{360k}{143}<150$ and $150<\frac{360k}{143}*12<180$

From first we'll get 12 values of k but 2nd I don't know how to work with as it should also be the remainder of 360. Please help so that for any given case like min hand between this and hour hand between that, I can find the value of k.

Comment: @BillDubuque While framing my question I was quite careful and also for the first time used MathJax myself. The changes/edits you made aren't apparent enough, perhaps subtle. I couldn't find the edits made by you on my account. Would love to know them so as to improve myself the next time, where can I check them and if not could you please inform me about them?

Comment: There were no edits to you question. Rather I removed the `number-theory` tag - which is for advanced questions. You can see that by clicking on the "edited n hours ago" link above.

Comment: Oh, Alright thanks for letting me know. Added that tag by checking similar questions as I was quite clueless about them. Thanks for editing though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between $4$ and $5$, let the **gap** by which the minute hand is ahead be $z$ **hours**. Then in the time the hour hand moves to $z$, the minute hand moves by $1-z$

so $\frac{1-z}{z} =12, z = \frac1{13},\; and \;(1-z) = \frac{12}{13}$ hrs.

This is simple enough to compute without calculator !

### PS:

OP apparently also wanted the starting and finishing times, and has posted  an answer after finding out which particular value of *k* applies here but it isn't really needed. Here's a simple way.

---

Starting between $4$ and $5$ and ending between $5$ and $6$,counting on the dial, we have the equations

$4 +M/12 = m ..... [I]$

$5+m/12 = M ... [II]$

which yields $M = \frac{768}{143},\;\; m = \frac{636}{143}$

To convert the **dial positions for minutes** to minutes, we need to multiply by $5$, yielding **times** as $\approx 4:26.85\;\;  and\;\; 5:22.24$

Hope this adds a simple tool to your armoury !

Comment: this is already discussed in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237818/minute-hand-and-hour-hand-interchange 
What I wanted to know was as to how to get the value of 'k' as mentioned in the question. For eg, the value of k in the 2nd question (pls refer my question) is 53 while that with respect to the 1st question is 118.

Comment: You have given so many references with wrong bits interspersed and so many other people commenting, that it is very difficult understand which formula has been obtained from which source. Can you add a self-contained question (by adding it) as **your** exact question/ doubt/need

Comment: Hey, I just observed an answer myself and posted, reading that, you'll know my need and would still love to know the answer by some mathematical gimmicks/tricks.

Comment: Wow! So crisp and simple and thus, beautiful and marvelous! Also checked and works for all values. Thanks a lot, that's what/how I wanted (mathematically). And I guess it's obvious enough how it works, that is, that the minute hand is 12 times faster than the hour hand. So, you found the values for both (before and after swap) using the same logic. Great!

Comment: Glad to be of help, and  glad that  you like it  (-:

Comment: By the way, before PS in your answer, what were you addressing?

Comment: It was the *duration of the gap* for reversal of hands between H:? min and (H+1):? min

Comment: Oh I see, alright

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to get/know the value of k is by pattern method.

In degrees:- Hour Hand = $\frac{360k}{143}$ and Min Hand = $\frac{360k}{143}*12$

The following can be observed: (keeping the above formula in mind will be helpful)

1. There are a total of 143 (unique) values that k can take, that are from 0 to 142.
2. From k = 143 we'll again start getting the repetition of the above results.
3. For every hour, from 0 to 10, we have 12 different values for swapped time.
4. For 11th hour, we have only 11 values (as 12th value is same as and counted in for the 0th hour).
5. For every hour (except 11), the swapped time's hour hand values are equally distributed from 0 to 11 (thus 12 in total confirming pt 3).
6. Even for the 11th hour, the swapped time's hour values are equally distributed but from 0 to 10 only.

So, we can generalize these results to come up with a formula that can help us get the value of k as follows:

For hour hand between $H_1$ and $(H_1+1)$ hr digits on the clock and the minute's hand between $M_1$ and $(M_1+1)$ hr digits on the clock, $$k=12\times H_1+M_1$$
For example, for your 2nd question, $H_1=4$ and $M_1=5$, so $k=12\times4+5=53$.

Note: $H_1$ & $M_1$ will be $0$ instead of $12$ when between $12$ and $1$ on the clock.

Since it helps seeing the pattern ourselves:

[image: Clock hands swapping results' snippet]

From left to right, the image contains the value of k, corresponding time before and after swap respectively.

Comment: If you just want values of k, you can tabulate all of them, but how will that help you for a particular problem ?

Comment: A person who left home between 4 p.m. and 5 p.m. returned between 5 p.m. and 6 p.m. and found that the hands of his watch has exactly changed places. When did he go out?
This was the question that was asked in one the links I copied in my question. To answer this question, we have H1 as 4and M1 as 5 thus getting k as 53 without the use of any pen and paper and within a minute. That's how it's useful.

Comment: Ok, good show !

Comment: @trueblueanil thank you

Comment: After finding $k = 53$, what are your computations of $4: ?$ and $5:?$

Comment: As mentioned in my question, in degrees:- Hour Hand = 360k/143 and Min Hand = (360k*12)/143. Putting k = 53, we get Hour Hand = 133.43 and Min hand = 1601.12 = 161.12 degrees. Now to convert degrees to hours, divide by 30 and to convert degrees to minutes, divide by 6.  So before swap we'll get 4 hours 26 mins and after swap, 5 hours 22 mins approximately.

Comment: PS: Added a simple way without the bother of finding *k*

Comment: @trueblueanil where? I can't find it.

Comment: You can see now, ha ha, I posted comments before PS !